# read files in python 3

Tags: python, printing

I'm learning how to read files and I want to know why this is happening and how to fix it. I made a .txt file just for practicing this and I have it in my documents. When I run the code though it tells me.

```
Errno2 no such file or directory: jub.txt
```

I have tried listing it as C:\Users and so on as well. I have watched tons of tutorials. Can some one please explain this to me so I can get it to work.

```
print ("Opening and closing a file")
text_file = open("jub.txt", "r")

print (text_file('jub.txt'))

text_file.close()
```

Comment: Is the file "jub.txt" in same path as the script ? Did you try to use the full path to the file ?

Comment: I have tried using the entire file location and it said the same thing. I am confused. I am copying every ones tutorials exactly.

Comment: If you were copying a tutorial exactly you wouldn't have written this: `print (text_file('jub.txt'))`

Comment: That's the way the guy wrote it. I just put in my file name. I'd appreciate it if you didn't assume things.

Comment: Then either the tutorial is utter and complete nonsense, or you've miscopied something. Without a link to the tutorial of course we can't say for certain, but I know which way I'd guess.

Comment: @TriGeo It seems more likely that you copied it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First check that your file exists in current directory, you can add this simple validation.
Secondly use with wrapper, it will close file for you after you exit this block. Thirdly: You read from file using read and readlines methods.

```
print ("Opening and closing a file")
f_name = "jub.txt"
if not os.path.exists(f_name):
  print 'File %s does not exist'%f_name
  return
with open(f_name , "r") as text_file:
   print (text_file.read())
```

For your path to be more precise, mayby use full system path, and not relative. Example: '/home/my_user/doc/myfile.txt'

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the code provided by Beri, I would rather use a try/except statement, and the new-style string formatting:

```
print("Opening and closing a file")
f_name = 'jub.txt'
try:
    with open(f_name, 'r') as text_file:
        print(text_file.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("File {} does not exist".format(f_name))
```

By the way I would recommend reading directly from the official Python doc, it's pretty clear and concise:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files